# Associate WAF with CloudFront distribution in China

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-waf

Looks like it's just not possible, but I still want to ask. There is no option in UI which allows you to do that, also you can't create WebACL in WAF using scope **CLOUDFRONT**, only **REGIONAL** is available.

But ALL docs in China is saying you can do that:

- https://docs.amazonaws.cn/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-awswaf.html
- https://docs.amazonaws.cn/waf/latest/developerguide/web-acl-associating-aws-resource.html
- https://www.amazonaws.cn/en/new/2021/amazon-waf-available-china/

AWS again lies to people and doing Google-translate of their docs or I am missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS CN Support confirmed that this feature is not yet supported in the China partition, referencing the documentation on implementation differences: https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/aws/latest/userguide/cloudfront.html#feature-diff

> Feature Availability and Implementation Differences
>
> - Amazon WAF, a web application firewall service, is not available.